# Reverse SSH tunneling with not localhost

Tags: ssh, tunneling

I have local computer and remote server. Remote server is isolated and is only accessible with this computer. I want to connect to site from server, let it be `https://example.com/site`

I tried to make a tunnel via `ssh -R 6761:example.com:80 remote-server`. But when I am trying to use `wget http://localhost:6761/site` on the remote server - it doesn't work and show 404 whilst `wget http://example.com/site` working well on local computer.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tunnel HTTP that way.

The name of the server you are trying to reach will be included in the request (the `Host` header), but it will most likely only listen to `example.com`, not `localhost`.

You will need to set up a HTTP *Proxy* (Forward Proxy) on your local machine and tell your http client(s) to use that. (How depends on the client.)